# matlab surface fitting not working a per expectation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have tried matlab's curve fitting which works well, but in case of surface fitting matlab is disregarding the second independent variable. Below is an example that replicates the problem.

```
function curve_fitting_test()
x1 = (1:100)';
x2 = (1:100)';
y = 10.*x1 + 20.*x2 + 30;
ft = fittype(@(a,b,c,x1,x2)a.*x1 + b.*x2 + c, 'independent', {'x1', 'x2'});
cf = fit([x1 x2], y, ft, 'start', [25 25 25], 'Lower', [0 0 0], 'Upper', [50 50 50])
```

This is the model which matlab is generating:

> ```
> General model:
> cf(x1,x2) = a.*x1+b.*x2+c
> Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
> a =          15  (15, 15)
> b =          15  (15, 15)
> c =          30  (30, 30)
> ```

Comment: noob question! sorry I asked that :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your input:

```
x1 = (1:100)';
x2 = (1:100)';
y = 10.*x1 + 20.*x2 + 30;
```

`y` is only calculated for the cases where `x1` = `x2` here, not all combinations.  Therefore, anything from `y = 30.*x1 + 30` to `y = 30.*x2 + 30` would be acceptable as long as `a + b = 30`.  You can see this by plotting your original data (black points) vs. the fit - the fit that MATLAB finds is perfectly acceptable for the data it has been given:

[image: fit surface vs original data]

The solution is to change your data input.  For example, just by changing `x1` and `x2` to random integers between 1 and 100, with all other code the same:

```
x1 = randi(100,100,1);
x2 = randi(100,100,1);
```

After fitting gives me:

```
 General model:
     cf(x1,x2) = a.*x1+b.*x2+c
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =          10  (10, 10)
       b =          20  (20, 20)
       c =          30  (30, 30)
```